# How to capture tcpdump to a compress file in linux

Tags: linux, compression, tcpdump, bzip2, bz2

I have a DNS server and I want to capture DNS traffic to get all the IPs which use my DNS server.

For this I start using following `tcpdump` command and capture them to a file:

```
tcpdump -n -i eth0 dst port 53 >> dns_data.log
```

But the file size is high when I run this for long time. How can I capture this to a compress file? I tried below command but its not working.

```
tcpdump -n -i eth0 dst port 53 | bzip2 -c >> dns_data.bz2
```

Comment: guessing that `bzip` doesn't know when the stream is closed, so it keeps waiting for more data. Check `man tcpdump` to see if there is an option "run for X (mins, secs, bytes) ? . Good luck.

Comment: Why not use querylog?

Answer (score 5):

Try something like `tcpdump -G 3600 -w 'trace_%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S.pcap' -z gzip`

**-G N** means rotate every N (3600) seconds.
**-z command** means run command(gzip) after rotation.

Comment: maybe you mean `...-w "$(date +trace_%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S.pcap)" -z ...` ? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter on a new enough tcpdump the `-G` option causes the `-w` option to be passed to `strftime` each time the file is rotated

Comment: @Alnitak : Thanks! Good to know.